# How to make a filter on survey data to plot it in Power BI using a unique Identifier for every participant of the survey?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, analysis, survey

I am currently examining a survey I ran for my group project in university and I would like to analyze it by using Power BI.

I was trying to create a slicer for every answer given from the survey. By clicking on this filter the amount of Answers should reduce/be filtered.

However, I have two problems right now:

**1. How can I make a question with all the possible answers to be filtered?**

Question 10: What color(s) does your bike have?
Blue
Green
Red
White
Black

Answers:
Person 1: Blue
Person 2: Red
Person 3: Black AND White

As of now: I have five slicer for question 10, which look like this:
10.1: The bike is = Blue --> Slicer: yes / no
... and so on.

**2. How can a filter be applied and the amount of possible answers reduced by the answers picked?**

I already tried to search for a solution but could not find anything. So if there is anything already up, I´d appreciate any link.

I really appreciate any advice or help in this matter.

Best Regards

Here is an idea of how my data table is looking like:
[Data Table of survey results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlyEa.jpg)

Comment: Your picture of your data table doesn't resemble your description of "... five slicer for question 10..." ?